# Is "a fair coin being tossed $n$ times" the same as "$n$ fair coins being tossed once"?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This is possibly a follow-up question to this one:

[different probability spaces for $P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k\big(1-p\big)^{ n-k}$?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process)

Consider the two models in the title:

- a fair coin being tossed $n$ times
- $n$ fair coins being tossed once

and calculate the probability in each model that "head" appear(s) $k~ (0\leq k\leq n)$ times. Then one may come up with the same answer that
$$
P(\text{"head" appear(s)} ~k~  \text{times}) = \binom{n}{k}p^k\big(1-p\big)^{n-k}
$$

However, the first one can be regarded as a [random process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process), where the underlying probability space is $\Omega = \{0,1\}$ ($1$ denotes "head" and $0$ for "tail") and the *time set* $T=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. While in the second one, the underlying probability space is $\Omega = \{0,1\}^n$.

Here are my questions:

- How can I come up with the *same* formula with these two *different* points of view?
- Are these two models essentially the same?

Comment: Yes, unless $n$ is very very large, in which case the coin might wear out!

Comment: In the first case, you are _assuming_ that there are $n$ _independent_ trials of the experiment of tossing a fair coin once.  In the second case, you are _assuming_ that the $n$ experiments with $n$ different fair coins are _independent_ experiments.  In both cases, you end up with a sample space $\{0, 1\}^n$ and the probability measure on this sample space comes from the _independence_ assumptions and is the same in both cases.  So, you _should_ get the same formula in both cases and the two models are essentially the same.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  When $n$ is very large, the first model assumes that one has a large amount of time to waste tossing the one coin, and the second model assumes that one has a large amount of money ($n$ coins!) and many hands to toss them all simultaneously!  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The models are essentially the same.  I think this automatically answers your first question as well.

You can see the two as trading a space dimension for a time dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Both models are basically a way to put a probability in $\{0,1\}^n$.

Usually you will be given a probability distribution in $\{0,1\}$,
and try to extend it to a probability in $\{0,1\}^n$, according
to some extra assumption.

If one experiment (tossing a coin)
does not influence the other (tossing it again, or tossing another coin),
then, you will have the model you describe.

The point is that when you talk about a random process,
usually you are allowing that the result of an experiment (toss a coin)
might influence the result of the next (toss it again).
Changing this condition, you might get a different probability
distribution in $\{0,1\}^n$.

For example, it might be assumed that when the outcome is $1$,
then the probabilities for the next outcome are flipped,
that is $p$ becomes $1-p$.
A more concrete example is the probability of a certain letter
appearing in a text. After a consonant, it will be likely that
the next letter will be a vogue. After a "p", we will not be likely
to get a "x" or a "w".